# Integrating Facebook Login with Parse Swift 3

Tags: swift, facebook, parse-platform, swift3

In my Xcode Project I already have a sign in feature that uses a user's username and password they created. Now I want to integrate a Facebook login in the project, but I am not completely sure how to do this. When someone makes an account through they way I have it now, they make and save a username and a password which can then be used in with `PFUser.logIn(withUsername: ..., password: ...)` for whenever they want to sign in again.

But with Facebook, I do not know what unique identifier I am suppose to save their account with. I know there is a Facebook id that I can extract, but how do I login the user in after I get this? Like I said before I currently use `PFUser.logIn(withUsername: ..., password: ...)` to log the users' in then I just use `PFUser.current()?.username` to get all data related to that user. I heard that I am suppose to use `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground` for this, but I already tried implementing it but when I press the "Continue with Facebook button", the app crashes (I screenshot error and placed it at bottom). I have copied my code of what I have so far. **How do I integrate a signup with Facebook feature that will allow me to save a users Facebook id and what method do I use to sign the user in (i.e. `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground`)?** Here's my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet var facebookSignUpButton: FBSDKLoginButton!
    var fullnameFB = String()
    var idFB = String()
    var emailFB = String()
    var isFBSignUp = Bool()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        signUpWithFacebook()
    }
    func signUpWithFacebook() {
        facebookSignUpButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile"]
        facebookSignUpButton.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(facebookSignUpButton)

    }
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil { //if theres an error
            print(error)
        } else if result.isCancelled { // if user cancels the sign up request
            print("user cancelled login")
        } else {
            PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(with: result!.token!) { (user, error) in
                if error == nil {

                if let user = user {

                    if user.isNew {
                        print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                    } else {
                        print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                    }

                    if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email") {
                        if let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email, name"]) {
                            graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? String())
                                } else {
                                    if let userDetails = result as? [String: String]{
                                        print(userDetails)
                                        self.fullnameFB = userDetails["name"]!
                                        self.idFB = userDetails["id"]!
                                        self.emailFB = userDetails["email"]!
                                        self.isFBSignUp = true
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("didnt get email")
                        self.createAlert(title: "Facebook Sign Up", message: "To signup with Facebook, we need your email address")
                    }

                } else {
                    print("Error while trying to login using Facebook: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "---")")
                }
                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? String())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Console output:

> 2017-08-12 14:14:33.223472-0700 Project[2423:1001235] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must initialize PFFacebookUtils with a call to +initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x188042fe0 0x186aa4538 0x188042f28 0x100b8f934 0x100b90020 0x100b9032c 0x10019eee8 0x1001a0a64 0x100867598 0x10086e998 0x10086e4f0 0x100871a94 0x18b3610d4 0x101521a10 0x101526b78 0x187ff10c8 0x187feece4 0x187f1eda4 0x189989074 0x18e1dd364 0x1001ec288 0x186f2d59c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: Could you post the log output once the app crashes ? `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground` works, so there must be another issue.

Comment: Okay I just edited the post with the error.

Comment: I meant the console output (as text, not an image). That's just an exception breakpoint in Xcode.

Comment: Ok I have changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs, you need to initialize `PFFacebookUtils` before using it, like so:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    // CODE...

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Important: **Must be done after Parse setup** (`Parse.initialize...`).

Comment: Wow now it worked! **What do I save in parse for when the user wants to get the stuff thats with their account?** For example, if the user sign up the normal way I just use their username they saved.

Comment: Nothing. The user row in Parse's User table is created by `PFFacebookUtils`. `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground` handles first time users (sign up) or existing ones (login).

Comment: Ah now I see that in parse it added a new row in my User class! But they automatically filled up the username column with a random string of text and the name and email strings are empty. I am already extracting the users name and email from their Facebook account so **how do I automatically put those in those columns when they first sign up? Also how do I check to see if this is the first time the user is signing in so they can change the random username Facebook assigns?**

Comment: Why do you want to change the username ? Usernames are only useful for user-passwords logins, not Fb. See the old post to check if it's a new user or existing one. You can set all the user's details after signup

Comment: Other users will be able to see the current user's username so they need to have the ability to change their username to one they like. Will changing the username Facebook gives them cause any bugs?

Comment: Don't think so. The user in those cases is auto-generated.